# Append the JSON Object Key with dynamic string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a request forming using the JSON Object something like this:

```
let formData = {
    name: classifierName,
    fire_positive_examples: {
        value: decodedPositiveExample,
        options: {
            filename: 'positive.zip'
        }
    },
    negative_examples: {
        value: decodedNegativeExample,
        options: {
            filename: 'negative.zip'
        }
    }
};
```

I want to inject a dynamic value from String instead of fire_positive_examples.

When trying to append a String, something like `let classNamePositive = className + '_positive_examples';` and have classNamePositive instead of fire_positive_examples, it instead has dynamic value it injects classNamePositive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

```
let formData = {
  name: classifierName
}
formData[classNamePositive] = ...
```

or

```
let formData = {
  name: classifierName,
  [classNamePositive]: ...
}
```